# Fast tags searching in PostgreSQL (arrays, GIN, seqscan)

Tags: postgresql

I have a table and a GIN index.

```
CREATE TABLE tags (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, tags text[], attrs text); 
CREATE INDEX tags_tags ON tags USING GIN("tags");
```

(`enable_seqscan` is on by default)

```
SET enable_seqscan TO on; 
SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tags @> array['category_72'];
```

Query runs in **1000-1600 ms**

```
SET enable_seqscan TO off; 
SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tags @> array['category_72'];
```

Same query runs in **1-10 ms** (100-1000 times faster).

Can somebody please clarify why is this happening and whether it's possible to hint PostgreSQL to use GIN index in query, without setting enable_seqscan to off.

Comment: Do you have statistics ? (run `vacuum analyze tags;` after creating the index)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I tried to do that now - that did not change the behavior.

Comment: do you get the same behaviour if you reverse the query order?

Comment: Yes it is very repeatable - I tried first and second variation many times - they are giving stable results. First is always slow, second is always fast;

Comment: how many records in db? explain of queries?

Comment: Not exactly the same table (it got bigger), but the same result  http://pastebin.com/81gySgnQ   Could it all be due to the fact that table is under constant writes? Is it possible to hint the optimizer to not use the seq scan except for SET?  The record count is about 70K

Answer (score 3):

Ok, there are a few things that I discovered that may answer my question.

When the table got bigger - PostgreSQL finally got to use the index.

If table is under constant writes - then GIN index is not used.